# Humming sound with emulator on windows xp

Tags: audio, android-emulator, windows-xp, soundcard

When I start any emulator on ma PC, I get annoying sound thru the speakers.. Like a filtered noise.

It doesn't stop unless I restart my PC...
I hv windows xp and two sound cards.. One was inbuilt with motherboard. I plugged another one when the first sound card stopped working.. Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove one sound card then try it again :D

Comment: How can I remove one from motherboard ... Its integrated with it

Comment: I hv tried disabling the driver from BIOS .. still m getting the noise cancellation .. or noise suppression .. pls help